# Cant connect to apache2 server with Ubuntu

Tags: networking, server, apache2

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-07-21 11:29:28 UTC; 2s ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 1443 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1447 (apache2)
      Tasks: 55 (limit: 4697)
     Memory: 4.8M
        CPU: 33ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
             ├─1447 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─1448 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             └─1449 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Jul 21 11:29:28 ghostsites systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jul 21 11:29:28 ghostsites systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

When I try to connect to my server with my ip, I found that I cant connect

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS x86/64

Comment: Do you see any attempts or errors being recorded in `/var/log/apache2/`? This is always the first place to look when an Apache server is not displaying sites.